# Extract and divide algorithm implementation in Elixir

Tags: recursion, integer, elixir

I just started learning Elixir and stumbled upon [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/171555/59487) over on [Programming Puzzles & Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com). It is a well-suited task for beginners, so I chose to give it a go (to be clear, *give it a go* means *solve it normally*, not [*golfing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_golf) it). To keep this question self-contained, here is the task – citing the linked post:

> For a given positive integer \$n\$:
>
> 1. Repeat the following until \$n < 10\$ (until \$n\$ contains one digit).
> 2. Extract the last digit.
> 3. If the extracted digit is even (including 0) multiply the rest of the integer by \$2\$ and add \$1\$ ( \$2n+1\$ ). Then go back to `step 1` else move to `step 4`.
> 4. Divide the rest of the integer with the extracted digit (integer / digit) and add the remainder (integer % digit), that is your new \$n\$.

For example, \$61407\$ gives \$5\$ when ran through this mechanism. I've come up with the following code:

```elixir
defmodule ExtractAndDivide do
  def extract_and_divide(x) do
    if x < 10 do x
    else
      head = div x, 10
      tail = rem x, 10
      case rem tail, 2 do
        0 -> head * 2 + 1 |> extract_and_divide
        1 -> div(head, tail) + rem(head, tail) |> extract_and_divide
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I'm seeking general advice, but mainly focusing on the following:

- Naming and Syntax better practices (usage of parenthesises, variable names etc.)
- Usage of `|>` (pipe) in this context. Would you ever see it used the way I did it in production code? Should I switch to "normal" notation instead?
- Less verbose or more elegant way to avoid the seemingly unaesthetic `if x < 10 do x ... else ... end` structure, perhaps using `case` would be better here?
- Is recursion the way to go? Should I stick to it or are there better, equivalent methods?

Comment: Since both clauses in your case end with the same pipe you could pipe the case. Have the 0 case just return head*2+1 and put the pipe after the case's end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have much to say about the pipe operator. It looks fine to me, although maybe some else has something to say...

As for the `if-else` clause, you can use [`cond`](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/case-cond-and-if.html#cond). It is basically a stylized `if` statement that looks like a `case` statement. One of your conditions can be `x < 10 ->` and the other default statement would be `true ->`.

I am not entirely sure if this is the best practice since the wording is a bit ambiguous in the documentation. Under the use case for `cond` it says the following:

> This is equivalent to `else if` clauses in many imperative languages
>   (although used way less frequently here).

Which I interpret to be `else if` clauses are used less often (implying that `cond` is often preferred).

Answer (score 2):

(untested)

```
defmodule ExtractAndDivide do
  def extract_and_divide(x) when x < 10, do: x
  def extract_and_divide(x) do
    head = div x, 10
    tail = rem x, 10
    up_or_down = rem tail, 2
    go_up_or_down(head, tail, up_or_down)
  end
  defp go_up_or_down(head, tail, up_or_down) when up_or_down == 0 do
    extract_and_divide(head * 2 + 1)
  end
  defp go_up_or_down(head, tail, _up_or_down_is_one) do
    extract_and_divide(div(head, tail) + rem(head, tail))
  end
end
```

The idea with having multiple conditional function clauses is twofold: it reduces nesting (and thus should increase readability), and - quite powerful - it allows to to easily test individual conditional parts. Whether to make the recursive call to extract_and_divide by piping the calculation through the function invocation or directly (like I did purely to show the alternative) is largely a matter of taste.

(note: skipped/circumvented potential nitpicking around naming and whether `up_or_down` shouldn't be a boolean; I just wanted to illustrate the pattern of doing logic by using multiple function heads)

Comment: The separate head to handle the x<10 case is good. The first function head for go_up_or_down could be simpler: `defp go_up_or_down(head, tail, 0) do`. There is no need to use a when clause for an exact match.